# how to print/store duplicate values in array in awk

Tags: arrays, shell, awk

I have two files. I want to print data of file1 on the basis of file2.

File1:

```
a 1 
b 2 
c 3 
d 4 
e 1 
f 5 
g 1
```

File2:

```
1 100
2 200
3 400
4 600
5 700
```

using below command :

```
 awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1;next}$1 in a{print a[$1] " " $2}' file1 file2
```

i got following output :

```
g 100
b 200
c 400
d 600
f 700
```

But i don't want duplicate values to be overwritten in array . 
Desired Output :

```
a 100
e 100
g 100
b 200
c 400
d 600
f 700
```

Is it possible to store duplicate key in array in awk script like multimap in C++. Or is there another way to do this ? Please help me out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If (and only if) the first fields of the second file (the single-digit numbers) are unique, you could turn the logic around and use that field as the key to the array:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR { a[$1] = $2; next } $2 in a {print $1, a[$2]} ' file2 file1
a 100
b 200
c 400
d 600
e 100
f 700
g 100
```

Now the output order is the order of file1, so not what you wanted, but a pipe to `sort -nk2` will fix that.

There's the border case of what to do if the first file has a line where the second field isn't in the second file (say, `h 9`). The `$2 in a` condition would skip those entirely. Without the condition they would be printed, with an empty second field (just `h[space]` in the output).

Comment: @Sundeep, true, that's better since it allows changing `OFS` if desired.

Comment: Got my vote. I was too focused on the `Is it possible to store duplicate key in array in awk script` part of the question and got sucked in by the OPs approach...

Answer (score 3):

With GNU awk for true multi-dimensional arrays:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2][$1]=$1;next} $1 in a{for (i in a[$1]) print a[$1][i], $2}' file1 file2
a 100
e 100
g 100
b 200
c 400
d 600
f 700
```

With other awks:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=a[$2] FS $1;next} $1 in a{split(a[$1],b); for (i in b) print b[i], $2}' file1 file2
a 100
e 100
g 100
b 200
c 400
d 600
f 700
```

Output order per key will be random due to the `in` operator, if that's a problem let us know what order you need.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `join` command.
Before `join` command, you must be use `sort` command to sort the files.

```
$ sort -k 2 file1 > file1_sort  
$ sort -k 1 file2 > file2_sort  
$ join -1 2 -2 1 file1_sort file2_sort -o 1.1,2.2 > new_file  
$ rm file1_sort  
$ rm file2_sort  
$ cat new_file
a 100
e 100
g 100
b 200
c 400
d 600
f 700
```

With [Process Substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution)

```
$ join -1 2 -2 1 <(sort -k2 file1) <(sort file2) -o 1.1,2.2
a 100
e 100
g 100
b 200
c 400
d 600
f 700
```

Comment: upvote for different and working solution... would be better if you could add explanation as well

Answer (score 1):

after first reply that replies to title but not OP itself, a second version for OP (original reply fully modified)

```
awk 'FNR==NR{R[$1]=$2;next}{$2=R[$2]}7' File2 File1
```

Comment: sorry, you are right this is the OP that was a bit confusing with *But i don't want duplicate values to be overwritten in array * meaning '*i want all value associate to line of File1 corresponding in File2*. The code remove duplicate (that doesn't exist in fact)

Comment: You should just delete it rather than adding a comment for us to forget it.